# C++: Can't use std::wstringstream

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c2079

For some reason, my project won't compile when I try to create a `wstringstream`:

```
std::wstringstream stringstream;
```

This causes error C2079:

> 'stringstream' uses undefined class
>   'std::basic_stringstream<_Elem,
>   _Traits, _Alloc> with [_Elem=wchar_t, _Traits=std::char_traits, _Alloc=std::allocator'

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Include `<sstream>` header

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the `stringstream` variable name.  The compiler is recognizing it as a type.  Try changing the variable name to something else as a test.

Comment: `std::wstringstream stringstream;` hints that the OP is not `using namespace std;` , so this probably isn't the issue.  But +1 anyhow, because it's still bad.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler complains that `wstringstream` is undefined. Normally if unicode is enabled this call should be included when you include `sstream`. Right-click your VC++ project, set :-

Configuration Properties -- > General -- > Character Set --> "Use Unicode Character Set"

See if this works for you...